# Reactstrap form isn't responsive

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

Hi i am writing page with form and i am using Reactstrap. Form working fine but it isn't responsive like here https://reactstrap.github.io/components/form/. I don't know what i have wrong there.

```
       <Col lg="6" className="no-padding full-page contact-us">
            <h1 className="h1-main">Objednejte se</h1>
            <hr className="hr-underline"/>

            <Container>
                <Form onSubmit={this.formSubmit} className="form-horizontal">
                    <Row>
                        <Col lg="6">
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="firstName" className="mr-sm-2">Jméno</Label>
                                <Input required onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.firstName}
                                       type="text"
                                       name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="Jan"/>
                            </FormGroup>
                        </Col>
                        <Col lg="6">
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="lastName" className="mr-sm-2">Příjmení</Label>
                                <Input required onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.lastName} type="text"
                                       name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Novák"/>
                            </FormGroup>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Col lg="6">
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="email">Email</Label>
                                <Input required onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.email} type="email"
                                       name="email" id="email" placeholder="jan.novak@gmail.com"/>
                            </FormGroup>
                        </Col>
                        <Col lg="6">
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="birthdate">Datum narození</Label>
                                <Input required onChange={this.handleChange} type="date"
                                       name="birhtdate" id="birhtdate" placeholder="date placeholder"/>
                            </FormGroup>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="message">Zpráva</Label>
                        <Input required onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.message} type="textarea"
                               name="message" id="message" placeholder="Napište nám důvod Vaší objednávky."/>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <div>
                            <CustomInput required type="checkbox" id="agreeCheckbox"
                                         label="Souhlasím se zpracováním osobních údajů."/>
                        </div>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <Button color="primary">Odeslat</Button>
                </Form>
            </Container>
        </Col>
```

on normal site look this form really good but on phone is too small. But i am not sure why. I wrote it with Reactstrap docs.

Thank you for your help :)

RESOLVE: Problem was that i forget add this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem may come from your lg="6" on the col.

You don't explain to your form how to react with smaller screen.

I think you can find the solution in the grid system of Bootstrap
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

For example, try to add a xs="12".

I hope the answer will help you.

Let me know the results.

Comment: So do you find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I understand. 
There is a style for your form other than bootstrap ? Or maybe on the container ? Or the body ?
Also watch this page, it can help you to remove some padding and margin in bootstrap
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/

Comment: Yes i sent screenshot in my last comment. Link is in text here. You can see there what happening me.

Comment: Yes,the link is for the result you have but not what you want if I understand well. So I'd like to see what you want like result